# Cannot set variable to CURRENT_DATE() in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, date, triggers

I am writing a trigger to insert tuples into a relationship table. In the process, I amm trying to insert the current date into one column, using the native CURRENT_DATE() function. I have tried multiple calls to CURRENT_DATE(), but there is a persistent problem getting the date into my today variable.
Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER AjouterChose
AFTER INSERT ON UneTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE aujourdHui DATE;
SET @aujourdHui := (SELECT CURRENT_DATE());
INSERT INTO AutreTable ER (IdProfil,Chose2,DateDebut)
VALUES (NEW.Responsable, NEW.IdChose2, @aujourdHui);
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

The MySQL error message is:

```
ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ...
for the syntax to use near ';
```

I've tried:

```
@aujourdHui
aujourdHui
(SELECT @aujourdHui)
(SELECT aujourdHui)
CURRENT_DATE()
(SELECT CURRENT_DATE())
```

None of these worked. Not sure what else is there to try.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that this does not work?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER AjouterChose
AFTER INSERT ON UneTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO AutreTable ER (IdProfil, Chose2, DateDebut)
        VALUES (NEW.Responsable, NEW.IdChose2, CURRENT_DATE);
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```